# Oracle set value in column when associated value is found in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery

I have two tables - referrals and bankruptcy.

Referrals

```
Referralno | bk_filed
----------------------
123        |
456        |
789        |
```

Bankruptcy

```
Referralno 
----------
875
123
789
```

I would like populate the bk_filed column with a "Y" if the referralno number matches in both tables.  Results would look like this.

```
Referralno | bk_filed
----------------------
123        | Y
456        |
789        | Y
```

I've tried the following merge statement but can't get it to work.

```
merge into LCTS.referrals r
using LCTS.bankruptcy b
on (r.referralno = b.referralno )
when matched then update
set r.bk_filed = "Y"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this as an `update` statement, using `exists` and a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
update referrals r
set bk_filed = 'Y'
where exists (select 1 from bankruptancy b wehre b.referralno = r.referralno)
```